# Dynamic paint gone when render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, dynamic-paint

I have a ocean scene where i had a ship model and i want to create foam of the ship with dynamic paint, but when i render the dynamic paint foam was gone. I tried to bake the dynamic paint but what happend was the foam still doesn't exist and the ocean texture gone. anyone has a solution?

Comment: I don't know if someone can find solution from such a low amount of informations. Attach your blend via https://blend-exchange.com/ or try to more carefully follow some tutorial.

Comment: @vklidu i mean about dynamic paint, it's gone when i render the scene. I already bake the dynamic paint but still doesn't appear when i render, maybe i just attach my scene so it be easier to understand

Comment: Is the “show in viewport” setting turned off for the dynamic paint system?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard the dynamic paint was seem alright and nothing wrong in the viewport, but when i render the dynamic paint was gone

Comment: Sorry, I meant the “show in render“ setting.